# How to get method signatures from a WSDL url using a Java code?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, url, wsdl

I'm working on a graphical web service builder site. I want to generate an java library for Android mobiles to access the each web service that clients build through the site. In order generate the library I want to get the method signatures (input argument name & data types, and return type) from a wsdl url through a java program. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Any suggestion would be very helpful instead of just putting a down vote :)

Comment: Please note that this site **is not** a free coding service. Show us what you tried and then we can help you. Your question, as is, is just too broad.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I'm working on a graphical web service builder site. I want to generate an java library for Android mobiles to access the each web service that clients build through the site. In order to generate the library I want to get the method signatures from the wsdl file..

Comment: What problems do you encounter when you get the WSDL data?